# Card to add second 4k display output to workstation

Tags: graphics-cards, 4k

I need a card that will give me another 4k HDMI or DP output on my Dell Inspiron 3668.

The case will hold a full-height card, but the power supply is weak so it won't support a hungry GPU.

(This is just for office use so I don't need a GPU.  Current MoBo has Intel HD Graphics 630 but only one HDMI output.)

Comment: You can use practically any GPU released in the last 5 years that has at least 1 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort. You can also just use the integrated Intel + any dedicated GPU for even more monitors at the same time.

Comment: @Romen Except most GPUs (a) use a lot of power, and (b) are expensive.  And all of the older ones I can find under $100 don't support 4k!

Comment: So upgrade the power supply.

Comment: @RohitGupta That doesn't work on the Dell PCs since they generally use a propriotary PSU

Comment: @feetwet maybe you can look into the 1650 or something like that? That one doesn't use too much power and supports 4k out

Comment: When I said "practically any GPU" I still meant the lowest end dedicated GPUs like a GT 1030. That model usually has 1 HDMI + 1 DisplayPort, supports 4K, and would be more than enough for "just office use". You never mentioned a budget of $100 so that was not considered by my suggestion. Add that to the question if it's relevant.

Comment: @Romen I'm really not up on GPUs so that helps: Searching for GT 1030 cards is turning up a bunch that claim to only use 30W!

Comment: @Romen Post as an answer so I can accept!  I just ordered a GV-N1030D4-2GL for $65.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much every GPU released in the last several years has 4K support and HDMI/DisplayPort connections. Even the "bottom of the barrel" GPUs have these features now.

The NVidia GT 1030 is one such card that usually does not have any extra power connector requirements and should support 2x 4K screens.

Be advised that you can continue to use your motherboard graphics with the new card too. For example if you need two DisplayPort connections and each only has one.